# Asynchronous Stored Procedure call in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, model-view-controller

I am new to C#. I'm trying to make an Asynchronous Stored Procedure call in my MVC ASP.net application.

This is what my code looks like:

```
public void RevalidateRule(int ruleKey)
    { 
        var conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ValidationModuleEntities"].ConnectionString;

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[ReValidateQuery]", conn);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ValidationRuleKey", ruleKey));
            command.CommandTimeout = 50;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

It has to be triggered whenever I press the save button in my view. However, it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried to debug and see what happens?

Comment: Is this the method that is invoked on save click?

Comment: Have you ascertained that this method is called? What seems to do nothing, the method or the proc?

Comment: That is not asynchronous at all... Also, if it's not doing anything, it's probably because it's not being called at all... have you tried to add a breakpoint there?

Comment: If its possible, please provide a [mcve]. Also, just a tip: Greetings and comments like 
Thanks in advance are not required on SO

Answer (score 0):

So you want to pass the value from your View to Controller and execute stored procedure. I'll try to explain how to get things done real quick.
Here is the example:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string data)
{
    int ruleKey = Convert.ToInt32(data);
    Helper helper = new Helper();
    helper.RevalidateRule(ruleKey);
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="text" name="data" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**Helper Class**

```
public class Helper
{
    public void RevalidateRule(int ruleKey)
    {
        var conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ValidationModuleEntities"].ConnectionString;

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[ReValidateQuery]", conn);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ValidationRuleKey", ruleKey));
            command.CommandTimeout = 50;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

So, this way you :

1. create your `HelperClass` to execute your stored procedure
2. pass needed value from your `View` to `Controller`
3. Execute your stored procedure.

Answer (score -3):

please write try catch in code.
where exactly you will get exception if anything going wrong in Store procedure

```
try
{
  var conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ValidationModuleEntities"].ConnectionString;

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[ReValidateQuery]", conn);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ValidationRuleKey", ruleKey));
            command.CommandTimeout = 50;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}
catch(exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: This is not the answer to OP's question, you could have mentioned this in a comment.